# ListFragments Contain Same List

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-viewpager, android-listfragment, android-tabs

I'm writing an app for my church that uses ListFragments with Tabs + Swipe navigation. If I only have tab/listfragment, it displays just fine. However, if I have multiple tabs, the list in each ListFragments is the same as the list of the last fragment. For example, if have tabs/listfragments Alpha, Beta, Gamma, and Delta, each ListFragment would contain the array list specified for Gamma.

Here is my code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener {

    // The context used for the Updater class
    public static Context context;

    PagerAdapter pagerAdapter;

    /*
     * I'm not entirely sure what this does, but it's key in implementing the
     * tab/swiping navigation. See documentation here:
     * http://developer.android.com
     * /reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html
     */
    ViewPager viewPager;

    // The AsyncTask class Updater
    public static Updater updater;

    public static ProgressDialog pd = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        context = getApplicationContext();

        // Sets up tabs
        pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

        // The method is called when a tab is clicked or the user swipes.
        viewPager
                .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                        actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                    }
                });

        // Creates tabs
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Life")
                .setTabListener(this), true);
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Ministries")
                .setTabListener(this));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("About")
                .setTabListener(this));
        /*actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Contact")
                .setTabListener(this));*/
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_settings:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    // Called when a tab is selected.
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

**PagerAdapter.java**

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /* Returns the correct fragment for each tab. */
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        Fragment returnFrag = null;
        Log.i("test", Integer.toString(i));

        switch (i) {
        case 0:
            returnFrag = new LifeFragment();
        case 1:
            returnFrag = new MinistriesFragment();
        case 2:
            returnFrag = new AboutFragment();
            // case 3:
            // returnFrag = new ContactFragment();
        }

        return returnFrag;
    }

    // I'm not quite sure why this method is here.
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }
}
```

**LifeFragment.java**

```
public class LifeFragment extends SherlockListFragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        /* Inflates view */
        View lifeView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container,
                false);

        return lifeView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {

        /*
         * The code below lists the options available under the "Life" tab. I'm
         * not sure why, but these have to go in the onResume() method.
         */

        /*
         * Specifies the array in the resources to get the array of option names
         * and the layout that the list is patterned after.
         */
        setListAdapter(ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(MainActivity.context,
                R.array.lifeList, R.layout.fragment_list_item));

        // Creates the actual list view
        ListView listView = getListView();

        // Disables searching through the list
        listView.setTextFilterEnabled(false);

        // The method called when a list item is clicked
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                // The intent to switch to
                Intent intent = null;

                switch ((int) id) {

                case 0:
                    intent = new Intent(MainActivity.context,
                            NewsActivity.class);
                    break;

                case 1:
                    intent = new Intent(MainActivity.context,
                            DailyScriptureActivity.class);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    intent = new Intent(MainActivity.context,
                            PrayerRequestActivity.class);
                    break;

                case 3:
                    intent = new Intent(MainActivity.context,
                            SermonActivity.class);
                    break;

                case 4:
                    intent = new Intent(MainActivity.context, WebActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("type", "payload");

                    // Getting data
                    dbAdapter dba = new dbAdapter(MainActivity.context);
                    dba.open();
                    Cursor cursor = dba.read("html_info", null, null);

                    while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
                        if(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")).equals("Plan-Of-Salvation")) {
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    intent.putExtra("data", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("html")));
                    intent.putExtra("title", "Plan Of Salvation");
                    break;
                }

                startActivity(intent);
            }

        });

        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

**MinistriesFragment.java**

```
public class MinistriesFragment extends SherlockListFragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        /* Inflates view */
        View lifeView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container,
                false);

        return lifeView;
    }

    /*
     * The method below lists the options available under the "Ministries" tab.
     */
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        /*
         * Specifies the array in the resources to get the array of option names
         * and the layout that the list is patterned after.
         */
        setListAdapter(ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(MainActivity.context,
                R.array.ministriesList, R.layout.fragment_list_item));

        // Creates the actual list view
        ListView listView = getListView();

        // Disables searching through the list
        listView.setTextFilterEnabled(false);

        // The method called when a list item is clicked
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                // The intent to switch to
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.context,
                        WebActivity.class);
                Cursor cursor = null;
                String where = null;
                dbAdapter dba = new dbAdapter(MainActivity.context);
                dba.open();

                /*
                 * This switch helps generate the "where" statement for the DB
                 * query
                 */
                switch ((int) id) {

                case 0:
                    where = "childhood";
                    break;

                case 1:
                    where = "royal-ambassadors";
                    break;

                case 2:
                    where = "upward";
                    break;

                case 3:
                    where = "high-school";
                    break;

                case 4:
                    where = "acteens";
                    break;

                case 5:
                    where = "MOPS";
                    break;

                case 6:
                    where = "senior-adults";
                    break;

                case 7:
                    where = "WMU";
                    break;

                case 8:
                    where = "recreation";
                    break;

                case 9:
                    where = "media-centers";
                    break;
                }

                cursor = dba.read("html_info", new String[] { "html" },
                        "'name'='" + where + "'");
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                intent.putExtra("type", "payload");
                intent.putExtra("data",
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("html")));
                intent.putExtra(
                        "title",
                        getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ministriesList)[(int) id]);
                startActivity(intent);
                cursor.close();
                dba.close();
            }

        });

        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

**AboutFragment.java**

```
public class AboutFragment extends SherlockListFragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        /* Inflates view */
        View aboutView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container,
                false);

        return aboutView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {

        /*
         * The code below lists the options available under the "Life" tab. I'm
         * not sure why, but these have to go in the onResume() method.
         */

        /*
         * Specifies the array in the resources to get the array of option names
         * and the layout that the list is patterned after.
         */
        setListAdapter(ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(MainActivity.context,
                R.array.aboutList, R.layout.fragment_list_item));

        // Creates the actual list view
        ListView listView = getListView();

        // Disables searching through the list
        listView.setTextFilterEnabled(false);

        // The method called when a list item is clicked
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                // The intent to switch to
                Intent intent = null;
                dbAdapter dba = new dbAdapter(MainActivity.context);
                dba.open();

                switch ((int) id) {

                case 0:
                    intent = new Intent(MainActivity.context, WebActivity.class);

                    Cursor serviceCursor = dba.read("html_info",
                            new String[] { "html" }, "'name'='services'");
                    serviceCursor.moveToFirst();
                    String serviceHtml = serviceCursor.getString(serviceCursor
                            .getColumnIndex("html"));
                    serviceCursor.close();

                    intent.putExtra("type", "payload");
                    intent.putExtra("data", serviceHtml);
                    break;

                case 1:
                    intent = new Intent(MainActivity.context,
                            SundaySchoolActivity.class);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    intent = new Intent(MainActivity.context, WebActivity.class);

                    Cursor wednesdayCursor = dba.read("html_info",
                            new String[] { "html" }, "'name'='wednesdays'");
                    wednesdayCursor.moveToFirst();
                    String wednesdayHtml = wednesdayCursor
                            .getString(wednesdayCursor.getColumnIndex("html"));
                    wednesdayCursor.close();

                    intent.putExtra("type", "payload");
                    intent.putExtra("data", wednesdayHtml);
                    break;

                case 3:
                    intent = new Intent(
                            android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                            Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=Lakeside+Baptist+Church,+2865+Old+Rocky+Ridge+Road,+Birmingham,+AL+35243"));
                    break;

                case 4:
                    intent = new Intent(MainActivity.context,
                            BlogActivity.class);
                    break;

                case 5:
                    intent = new Intent(MainActivity.context, WebActivity.class);

                    Cursor feedCursor = dba.read("html_info",
                            new String[] { "html" }, "'name'='wednesdays'");
                    feedCursor.moveToFirst();
                    String feedHtml = feedCursor.getString(feedCursor
                            .getColumnIndex("html"));
                    feedCursor.close();

                    intent.putExtra("type", "payload");
                    intent.putExtra("data", feedHtml);
                    break;

                case 6:
                    intent = new Intent(MainActivity.context, WebActivity.class);

                    Cursor historyCursor = dba.read("html_info",
                            new String[] { "html" }, "'name'='wednesdays'");
                    historyCursor.moveToFirst();
                    String historyHtml = historyCursor.getString(historyCursor
                            .getColumnIndex("html"));
                    historyCursor.close();

                    intent.putExtra("type", "payload");
                    intent.putExtra("data", historyHtml);
                    break;
                }

                /*
                 * Adding the title to every intent, whether it is needed or
                 * not.
                 */
                intent.putExtra(
                        "title",
                        getResources().getStringArray(R.array.aboutList)[(int) id]);

                startActivity(intent);
                dba.close();
            }

        });

        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

**fragment_list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</FrameLayout>
```

**fragment_list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:linksClickable="true"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="Value"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#000000" />
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Thank you in advance for the help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what the difference is, but I changed by PagerAdapter code up to use a list of Fragments instead of a switch. Now, the app runs great :D

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    private List<SherlockListFragment> fragList = Arrays.asList(
            new LifeFragment(), new MinistriesFragment(), new AboutFragment(),
            new ContactFragment());

    /* Returns the correct fragment for each tab. */
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        return fragList.get(i);
    }

    // I'm not quite sure why this method is here.
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }
}
```